# Best way to split the layers of a TIFF with imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, tiff

Is it possible to do with imagemagick and if so what would be the command?

so far i've tried to split the tiff with

```
convert a.tif -scene 1 a%d.tif
```

but the resulting image has all layers.

Please advise, thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you want to separate the channels? If so, use `convert full.jpg -channel R -separate red.jpg`

Comment: The command you posted in your question works fine for me (thanks for that! :P), so I would report this as a bug if it doesn't work for a given image.